# What does $|x⟩|0⟩$ actually mean in bra-ket notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus, quantum-computer, notation

Consider the following quote from [Wikipedia's page on Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Quantum_part:_Period-finding_subroutine):

> Initialize the registers to
>
> $Q^{-1/2} \sum_{x=0}^{Q-1} \left|x\right\rangle \left|0\right\rangle$
>
> where $x$ runs from 0 to $Q-1$. This initial state is a
>   superposition of $Q$ states.

I am having a hard time getting what $\left|x\right\rangle \left|0\right\rangle$ actually is. Is it outer product of ket $x$ and ket $0$? Or what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 8):

Juxtaposing two kets is, except on rare occasions, a shorthand for the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) (try also [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces) for a gentler introduction) of the two vectors, which would be written in full as $|x\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$.

Comment: In this particular context it maybe worth mentioning that $| x \rangle$ is itself a tensor product of qubit kets corresponding to the binary representation of $x$.